# How to map the value in template by getting the reference from other object label?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-template

In my app, I have 2 object ( as a sample ), from first object I required the respected value. from another value I have one a `value` label. how how can i combine both in `template` ?

here is my try :

```
object:Object = { 'name' : 'Afzil' };
value:string = 'name';
```

Template :

```
<h1 style="font-size: 20px;">{{object.value.name}}</h1>
```

As of now, I am getting an error. But I expect this in output:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 20px;">Afzil</h1>
```

This is nothing but getting a value from one request from server and property from other http request.

Comment: what is the error.?

Comment: are you looking for {{ object[value] }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get 'value' key that doesn't exist in obj.

Try `{{ object[value] }}`

It will look for 'value' key.

Comment: Works fine. can't I use the `.` notation? or any other simplified ways?

Comment: you can use . notation if you have obj like object:Object = { 'name': { first: 'abc', last: 'xyz' }}. Then you can write {{ object[value].first }}